# How to collect a Observable<ResultSet> to Map

Tags: rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to collect a `Observable<ResultSet>` from Vertex AsyncSqlClient
to HashMap.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap();
asyncSQLClient
        .getConnectionObservable()
        .flatMap(sqlConnection -> sqlConnection.queryObservable("select a, b from table")
                .doOnCompleted(sqlConnection::close)
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while querying.", throwable)))
        .flatMap(resultSet -> Observable.from(resultSet.getRows()))
        .toBlocking()
        .forEach(row -> map.put(row.getString("a"), row.getInteger("b")));
```

but this seems to block forever.

After searching a while without any result, would you mind lending me a hand?

Comment: Do you have onComplete called in your upsteam? toBlocking() need that to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Phoenix Wang commented, the `forEach()` method [will block until Observable will completes](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html#forEach(rx.functions.Action1)).  meaning it will block forever if you have `Observable` that emit infinite items or you have an Observable that incorrectly do not emit `onCompleted` to signal Observable complete.

That might caused by your `getConnectionObservable()` method implementation, if it's creates a custom `Observable`, using `Observable.create()` for instance, you must call `onCompleted()` after all items were emitted.

Anyhow, you should be aware that `toBlocking()` will block and wait, that might not be appropriate with production code (as it's breaking all the purpose of reactiveness), you can achieve the same purpose using `reduce()`:

```
 asyncSQLClient
            .getConnectionObservable()
            .flatMap(sqlConnection -> sqlConnection.queryObservable("select a, b from table")
                    .doOnCompleted(sqlConnection::close)
                    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while querying.", throwable)))
            .flatMap(resultSet -> Observable.from(resultSet.getRows()))
            .reduce(Maps.newHashMap(), (map, o) -> map.put(row.getString("a"), row.getInteger("b")))
            .subscribe(map -> {
                        //do something with map
                    }
            );
```

note, you still need to solve the `onCompleted` issue as reduce will also expect `Observable` completion and will emit signal item when source `Observable` completes.
Additional option is to use `scan()` (just replacing reduce with scan), with scan you will get emission for each item emitted with source `Observable`, meaning you will accumulate items to map over time.

Comment: Is it possible to use the `single` operator to limit the 'length' of the Observable to 1? To signal that the Observable is complete after the first element?

Comment: no, as single() will also wait for completion (or for second emission and then will throw IllegalArgumentException, nevertheless, you can use first(), there you will get the first emission no matter what will happen afterwards

Comment: but it's seems to me like a band-aid solution, you can post your `getConnectionObservable` code if you need help to figure it out.

Comment: @FranzEbner if you want just the first element. use `firstElement()/take(1)`

Comment: @yosriz I'm using io.vertx.rxjava.ext.asyncsql.AsyncSQLClient to get the first observable

Comment: now I see (also the `sqlConnection.queryObservable` is vertx), well, in this case it's hard to tell where the problem exactly,  I would have debug this by  logging at doOnComplete at several places to get sense what Observable causing the problem